# Symfony2:BBCode presentation and insertion

Tags: symfony, bbcode

i am working on a project...with many database content in BBCode (Forum posts...etc).

is there a bundle or solution to present that "out of the box" without me having to invent wheel in Symfony?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://github.com/helios-ag/FMBbCodeBundle

Comment: awesome...but also how do i represent stuff coming from DB like a comments field with content `[b]hey, your reply is awesome[/b]` as html `<strong>Hey, your comment is awesome</strong>`...i am not sure this bundle does this already?

Comment: my applogies...the documentation says it well '{{'[b]Bold text[/b]'|BBCode}}<br />' ....so it works fine :) thanks for the hint.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

> [FMBbCodeBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMBbCodeBundle)
>
> PHP-Decoda integration in Symfony2
>
> A lightweight lexical string parser for BBCode styled markup.

Comment: thanks for your hint. But the bundle lacks many things in documentation, and the implementation caused me many errors.

Comment: true :) i posted an issue maybe we get further here https://github.com/helios-ag/FMBbCodeBundle/issues/1